# Redirecting the debug trace of perl script to a file

Tags: perl, debugging, perl-module

Ex:  perl -d:Trace testScript.pl > output.log

Q:1 The traces are not redirected to the output.log file.
How to redirect the trace.

Q:2 Is it possible to trace the script only as in the trace it goes into the module too used in the script. Can we trace one or two level only.

Thanks.

Comment: Building from @jonathan, can you say what Linux shell you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A:1 The traces are redirected by default to the stderr stream. 
To log to stderr (in general in Linux), you do the following:

```
perl -d:Trace testScript.pl &2> output.log
```

Where &2 equates to stderr, &1 is stdout (i.e. printf debugging), and both would be just &

I am not sure about A:2.

Comment: Do you want to check your redirection notation?  As written (`&>2`), `bash` would treat that as 'run perl in background; send standard error of empty command to output.log'.  You probably mean `2>&1` where the 1 is optional but very explicit. (There was a bug in an old (mid-90s) version of a Windows emulation of shell that required the 1 to work at all, so I got in the habit of typing it).

Comment: He only want '2>&1' if he wants stderr to go to the same place as stdout.  if he wants sderr to the file while stdout does not change then he wants '2&>'.

Comment: @LenJaffe: yes, you're right; the original was attempting to send stderr to the file, not the same place as stdout.  The rest of the analysis applies, though — I think.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - which is why I only critiqued the redirection.